# Xml file image over image

Tags: java, android

i want to create a listView with swipe (front and background) from here:

https://github.com/47deg/android-swipelistview

https://github.com/47deg/android-swipelistview-sample/

i created an xml file which defines the row element:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>



    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >



    <RelativeLayout 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/front"
            android:tag="front" 
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:background="#ffffff">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView01"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/ImageView01"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:textSize="18sp"

                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine" />

        </RelativeLayout>





    <LinearLayout 
                      android:layout_width="match_parent"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:orientation="horizontal"
                      android:id="@+id/back"
                      android:background="#e3e3e3"  
                     android:tag="back"
                     android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                     android:layout_marginRight="5dp"

                      >

                      <Button
                          android:id="@+id/deleteBtn1"
                          android:layout_width="150dp"
                          android:layout_height="100dp"

                          android:text="Delete" />

                      <Button
                          android:id="@+id/UpdateBtn1"
                          android:layout_width="150dp"
                          android:layout_height="100dp"

                          android:text="Update" />

                  </LinearLayout>    





</FrameLayout>
```

and the listview xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

                <EditText android:id="@+id/EditText01"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:hint="Search">                               
                </EditText>

    <com.fortysevendeg.android.swipelistview.SwipeListView
        xmlns:swipe="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/example_lv_list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/profile_listview_back"
        android:listSelector="#00000000"
        swipe:swipeActionLeft="dismiss"
        swipe:swipeActionRight="reveal"
        swipe:swipeBackView="@+id/back"
        swipe:swipeCloseAllItemsWhenMoveList="true"
        swipe:swipeFrontView="@+id/front"
        swipe:swipeMode="both" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

however when i run this listview, it shows me the background over the front(i want that only when i swipe the front it will show me the back)

i want that the delete and update button will show only when swipe the front..

how can i solve it? thanks alot

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In your row-layout you should have the LinearLayout before RelativeLayout

It's important the order of elements

```
<LinearLayout>

  .... buttons ....

</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout>

  .... image and text ....

</RelativeLayout>
```